# Android HTTPS SSL reuse and caching

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, reusability

I know this has been asked several times. I've tried them all but none of them work as I want.
I'm polling a webservice repeatedly in 30 second intervals. The webservice is based on HTTPS / SSL. I want to remove the overhead of SSL handshake on each webservice call ( SSL reuse). How can I achieve this?

I've looked at `SSLCertificateSocketFactory` and `SSLSessionCache` which seems to be the answer. I can get an `SSLSocket` instance by calling

```
SSLSocketFactory sockFactory = SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory(TIMEOUT, sslSession);
```

However I cannot find a way to set my keystore and password to this socket factory. I guess you can set the keystore and password only via an `SSLSocketFactory` constructor.

So my 2 problems are 
1) Need SSL reuse
2) Need to use my keystore for accepting the certificates from the server.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered keeping the connection alive to the server at all times? The overhead, processing requirements and power usage of establishing a connection may not be worth it if you're doing it every 30 seconds.

Comment: thanks for the thought my i need it to be each separate web service

Comment: SSL session pooling should be automatic. Are you sure you aren't getting it? SSL but sessions might expire sooner than 30 seconds.

Comment: EJP - I used wireshark to monitor the network traffic and unfortunately I find that, even with an interval of 10 seconds the handshakes are being done each time.